# Getting text value to Controller using jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My text box and button

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ClaimNumber" placeholder="Enter a claim number"
                id="ClaimNumber" />               
<button class="btn btnNormal" type="submit" id="btnSearch">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSearch").on("click", function () {
            var enteredClaimNumber= $("#ClaimNumber").val();
            alert(enteredClaimNumber);
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ClaimsSearch",
            data: enteredClaimNumber
        });
    });
});
```

My controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClaimsSearch(string enteredClaimNumber)
    {
        _lfAPI.ClaimsAdvanceSearch(enteredClaimNumber);
        return View();
    }
```

I'm not able to get the value in controller..Thanks in advance..

Comment: `data: {enteredClaimNumber: ClaimNumber}`?

Comment: data : "&enteredClaimNumber="+ClaimNumber, try this it will work

Comment: The control is coming to controller, but value is shown as null...

Comment: As you have edited the post, use `data: {enteredClaimNumber: enteredClaimNumber}` The `name : value`, `name` should match controller method param name; and the `value` should match the javascript variable/value you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

Data in AJAX request must be like name, value pair:

```
data: {"enteredClaimNumber": ClaimNumber}
```

Write like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSearch").on("click", function () {
            var ClaimNumber = $("#ClaimNumber").val();
            alert(enteredClaimNumber);
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ClaimsSearch",
            data: {"enteredClaimNumber": ClaimNumber}          
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The property name must match the action parameter `enteredClaimNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var datum = {"claimNum": ClaimNumber};  
$.ajax ({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "/Home/ClaimsSearch",
     dataType: "json",
     data: JSON.stringify(datum),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

![Check This][1]

In 
 data : { parameter : value }

if there are multiple parameter then separate with comma (,) 
data : { parameter1 : value1,parameter2 : value2 }
 
 as shown below 
 $.ajax({ 
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { input: $('#caption').val() }, 
            success: function (result) { 
                alert(result.name); 
            }, 
            error: function () { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });